# How do I create a copy of a picture to a specific path in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 system a c# winform and a php and their database is stored in a single database mysql now my problem is storing pictures...., in my html I save my pictures in htdocs/"foldername"/productimages now what I want in my C# winform was get the location path of the picture from open dialogue and copy that picture to the specific folder which is the htdocs/"foldername"/productimages how do i do that

my code

```
    string picloc;
    private void UpdBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dlg.Filter = "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.png)|*.png|ALL Files(*.*)|*.*";
        dlg.Title = "Select Thumbnail";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Result();
            picloc = dlg.FileName.ToString();
            pic1.ImageLocation = picloc;

        }
    }
```

so How do I copy the file picture from the string picloc to the specific loc?

Comment: have you tried `System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);`

Comment: Ok gonna tried that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this. Something like the following should manage the copy for you:

```
string picloc;
string new_loc;
private void UpdBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dlg.Filter = "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.png)|*.png|ALL Files(*.*)|*.*";
    dlg.Title = "Select Thumbnail";
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Result();
        picloc = dlg.FileName.ToString();
        pic1.ImageLocation = picloc;
        File.Copy(picloc, new_loc); // new_loc being the new location for the file.
    }

}
```

This assumes you already know the location for the copy of the file. If you want to give the user the choice, do so via a SaveFileDialog to get the new location (as a string) and then perform the copy.

Comment: thanks btw aditional question How do I get the filename of the path? example c/newfolder/image1.jpg so how do I get the "image1.jpg" only

Comment: Path.GetFileName is what you need. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: path.getfilename? so like Path.GetFileName(new_loc)?

Comment: Yep, exactly that. Follow the link as there's code examples on the page. Actually you should make an effort to get familiar with reading the MSDN documentation, it will become you're first port of call for a lot of questions when you get used to it.

Comment: why do I get an unrecognize escape secquence?